# Checking A Folder Exists And redirecting Into It In PHP

Tags: php, url-routing

How can I check if a folder exists and the redirect the url into that folder in php

Comment: There's a difference between a folder existing on the filesystem and it being accessible on the web. In fact something that looks like a folder in a url may not be there at all. Do you mean checking whether a particular url is valid?

Comment: "promo" is my root folder in that folder there have a folder "logo" i want to check logo is exist in promo using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the directory using `is_dir($path)`. Then you can `chdir($path);` to the existing location.

If you want to redirect (a browser) to another url you use `header( 'Location:'.$url ) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for

```
if(is_dir($dirname)) 
{
  header("location: ".$dirname);
}
```

im sorry, its header("location: $dirname);

Comment: when iam using this an error occured "Fatal error: Call to undefined function location() "

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_dir() function for checking if directory exists or not.

[For further reference](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)